# Fetching specific columns from PDF to Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, pdf, vba

I have been given a PDF that has a table in it, I have to write three of its columns to an Excel sheet using VBA. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

1. I would say this is (almost[1]) impossible (and if not, it highly depends on the specific PDF file and its structure). Think of PDF file as it was a printed paper, then you can imagine how hard it would be for an algorithm to extract a table of it.
2. There are no built in tools in VBA for parsing PDF files.

*[1] almost in the meaning of: You can do anything with programming if you are good enough.*